# Is it against the rules to make ChatGPT generate a text and ask questions about how that text is grammatical or not?

Tags: discussion, chatgpt

I made it write poetry and sometimes, the output doesn't seem to be grammatical or correct at all. Is it ok if I base some of my questions on output generated by ChatGPT?

Comment: I can tell you this much, if you say that a text is from ChatGPT and you would like to know if it's grammatical you will get **at least one user** voting to close your question for one of three reasons: 1. it's proofreading regardless of where or who created the piece 2. the lines or text are not generated by a human 3. they personally hate ChatGPT. There's also a 4th reason, interpretation of  poetry and lyrics is normally considered as Literature critique, which is based on opinion.

Comment: But if the question is interesting, has research, and the answers posted will be *useful* for more people other than yourself. I'd say it stands a reasonable of chance of staying open.

Comment: @Mari-LouA All of that would make a good answer

Comment: Why would you expect poetry to be grammatical?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a way this could be a good idea for the site.

Since you're a high-rep user with many successful questions, I'm sure you know that all questions on this site must be about learning some specific aspect of the English language. Proofreading questions are off-topic, so you would have to frame your question about some aspect of ChatGPT's language use, like a grammar point or vocabulary use that you are unsure about. This is probably not an issue with you, but worth mentioning up top because I'm sure many learners here have similar ideas.

The only situation where we are lenient about the proofreading rule is where the cited passage is from a **highly reputable source**, like a prominent news organization or a respected dictionary. These sources nearly always have very high-quality, natural English, so if a learner believes it's wrong, it's usually an opportunity for learning, so a great question to ask. And I love answering those questions. But **ChatGPT is not at all such a source**.

Further, if you're asking it to write poetry, this gives it licence to ignore the rules of grammar and vocabulary usage, so that might be what you're encountering.

And FWIW, the reality on this site is that a good portion of the users here strongly dislike ChatGPT, and will DV/CV on sight and take to the comment section or even Meta to rally support against it.